# Fatal error: Trait 'App\Commenter' not found

Tags: php, laravel-5

I am new to laravel and php

I am using [Actuallymab/comment](https://packagist.org/packages/actuallymab/laravel-comment) to make a comment system for my app.

I tested it with this :

**testcommenteract.php**

```
<?php

require __DIR__.'/../vendor/autoload.php';
$app = require_once __DIR__.'/../bootstrap/app.php';

use App\User;
Use App\Post;

$user = App\User::first();
$product = App\Post::first();

// $user->comment(Commentable $model, $comment = '', $rate = 0);
$user->comment($product, 'Lorem ipsum ..', 3);

// approve it -- if the user model `canCommentWithoutApprove()` or you don't use `mustBeApproved()`, it is not necessary
$product->comments[0]->approve();

// get avg rating -- it calculates approved average rate.
$product->averageRate();

// get total comments count -- it calculates approved comments count.
$product->totalCommentsCount();
```

It gives me this error:

```
Fatal error: Trait 'App\Commenter' not found in C:\xampp2\htdocs\galaxall\app\User.php on line 15
```

please help

Comment: You would need to `require` the autoload file within laravel. This is done by the application. Where is the `testcommenteract.php` located?

Comment: Can you also post your `User` and `Product` models please

Comment: @thisiskelvin At the root of the application

Comment: `Commentor` should be within the app folder not the root.

Comment: Oh.Thanks.But I was feeling hopeless coz no one answered by question for a long time so I stopped laravel.Thanks a lot u saved me

Comment: Not to worry. I've added as an answer so mark as correct/complete. Please use the docks or user laracasts to learn more. It is a very good framework

Comment: Share your app\User.php code. You either have to check your 'namespace-ing' or add 'use App\Commenter' at the top of app\User.php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Models, by default, should be added to the `app` folder. Furthermore, with Laravel there shouldn't be a need to require the autoload file as this is done within the framework.